# Python running program at a certain time

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I've built a crawler using Scrapy to crawl into a site and extract links. I want the crawler to run everyday at a certain time. I found out the python's [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.enter) to perform scheduling but i could not find out where to start from. Any help would be highly useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is where you should look into the operating systems scheduler. On linux and alike you would typically use cronjobs:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

On MS Windows you would typically use Windows Task Scheduler:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7